# Squat bar path turning C shaped, possible causes?

Tags: squats

When I squat, I notice that my bar path often turns into a C like shown below:

[image]

Now here is what I tried to fix it so far:

1. Keeping back tight
2. Valsalva Maneveur
3. Foot placement (balancing over mid foot)
4. Rotating legs as I go down

And, I tried making an push of hip to back as I started going down, still nothing helps. Ideas?

[Video Example](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/CveE2pTI77o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your bar path is correct. The bar is not supposed to travel in a vertical line in a squat.**

In the bottom position of a squat, the point on the legs that is above the midfoot will typically be around 1/4 of the way from the knee to the hip. This means that of the lifter's body, only their knees, head and shoulders will be in front of their midfoot, and the majority of the thighs and torso will be behind the midfoot. That's a whole lot of bodyweight that is sitting behind the feet, and the only way that the lifter can balance in this position is to have some weight in front as a counterbalance. That's where the barbell comes in to the balance equation.

The bar must move forward in order to act as a counterbalance to your butt moving backwards as you descend. The heavier the bar is, the less it will need to move forwards to achieve this. The bar path follows a curve like the top half of a left parenthesis "(", in that it begins with a lot of forward movement, and then becomes more vertical (after it has moved forwards of the feet) towards the bottom of the movement.

The website https://mysquatmechanics.com/ has a good model of this movement, however it doesn't seem to current be maintained and is only displaying well on mobile for me, not on a computer.

This is the same reason why Smith machines are typically designed to move the bar on an angle, rather than straight up and down. The machine is trying to approximate the natural bar path of a squat.

Reference: https://www.strongerbyscience.com/how-to-squat/

Answer (score 1):

Could be a bunch of things, but tight hips and mid/upper back are likely.

I'd suggest going a little slower on the way down, focus on "chest up", and begin your lifelong journey of doing flexibility/mobility work in the ankles, hips, and thoracic spine.

Comment: How does one get started on this journey?

Comment: Good question — I don't have a great answer. I started with stuff like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBHzXF-mVjY and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3UGl2rHz18 and just kind of explored what I needed to do. A more systematic approach might be better.